# Converting my script to use getRangeData instead of using an iterative loop (GoogleAppScript)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am having issues converting my last script to work with getDataRange. I got some help converting my original functions, seen below:

```
function twentyDKP() {

  alertBox20DKP()

}

function alertBox20DKP() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=sh.alert("Add 20 DKP to all raiders?", sh.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(response==sh.Button.YES) {

    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var raiders = activeSheet.getRange(1, 12).getValue();

    // In your situation, the range is the same. So "range" is declared here.
    var range = activeSheet.getRange(4, 2, raiders);

    // Create values for putting to the range.
    var values = range.getValues().map(function(row) {return [row[0] + 20]});

    // Put the created values to the range.
    range.setValues(values);

    // Update the cells. Before "alert" is shown.
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var complete=sh.alert("20 DKP has been added to all raiders.", sh.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

However, I now want to do the same with my subtraction script that would rely on two ranges of data. I'm still very new to coding, and am basically getting by on youtube tutorials and advice from this forum. How would I implement the same change to the below code?

```
function spentDKP() {

  alertBoxSpentDKP()

}

function alertBoxSpentDKP() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=sh.alert("Subtract spent DKP of all raiders?", sh.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(response==sh.Button.YES) {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var raiders = activeSheet.getRange(1, 12).getValue()+4;

  for(var i=4;i<raiders;i++){
   var DKP = activeSheet.getRange(i,2).getValue()
   var spentDKP = activeSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
   if(spentDKP>0){
   activeSheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(DKP-spentDKP)
  }
  }
  var complete=sh.alert("All DKP has been subtracted, please clear the loot window to reset values.", sh.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

```
var raiders = activeSheet.getRange(1, 12).getValue()+4;

for(var i=4;i<raiders;i++){
  var DKP = activeSheet.getRange(i,2).getValue()
  var spentDKP = activeSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
  if(spentDKP>0){
    activeSheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(DKP-spentDKP)
  }
}
```

with this

```
var raiders = activeSheet.getRange(1, 12).getValue();

var range = activeSheet.getRange(4, 2, raiders, 3); // Get the range with the data to be processed
var inputValues = range.getValues(); // Get the data from that range
var outputValues = inputValues.map(Subtract); // Use a function to subtract the spent DKP from the DKP balance available
range.setValues(outputValues); // post the calculated values back to the sheet
```

And add a helper function for map:

```
// Helper function for map
function Subtract(inputValuesRow) {
  if (inputValuesRow[2] > 0) {   
    inputValuesRow[0] -= inputValuesRow[2];
  }
  return inputValuesRow; // This has now been change where column 4 value has been subtracted from the column 2 value 
}
```

**Edit**

To preserve the formulas in the middle column, remove the Subtract helper function. And use this as the replacement:

```
var raiders = activeSheet.getRange(1, 12).getValue();

var range = activeSheet.getRange(4, 2, raiders, 3); // Get the range with the data to be processed
var inputValues = range.getValues(); // Get the data from that range

var outputValues = [];
for (var r = 0; r < inputValues.length; r++) {
  if ( inputValues[r][2] > 0 ) {
    outputValues.push([inputValues[r][0] - inputValues[r][2]])
  } else {
    outputValues.push([inputValues[r][0]])
  }
}
activeSheet.getRange(4, 2, raiders, 1).setValues(outputValues);
```

Comment: That works for subtractions, many thanks, but it seems to be returning values to column 4 as well as column 2. Column 4 contains formulas which I don't want overwritten. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sure. Please see my edit above. This will overwrite the values in column 2 and preserve the formulas in columns 3 and 4.